# Unable to add Rediffmail account in Gmail app

Tags: applications, gmail, accounts

I was trying to add my Rediffmail account to Gmail app. After choosing any of POP or IMAP, it says *unable to connect server*.

I have other mail accounts in the app and all of them are working fine.

How to add Rediffmail account in Gmail app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select POP3 → In POP server address, type `pop.rediffmail.com` → in SMTP server address, type `smtp.rediffmail.com`.  Then you are all set.

Comment: smtp.rediffmail.com doesn't work. I keep getting authentication failure error, although I made sure I am typing correct password

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach final stage where it asks for SMTP details, just prefix with `smtp.` and click on next. You are done.

I did it on my own and it worked fine.